# Have Dynamic Controls fire Javascript functions as Event Handlers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net page.  As a proof-of-concept, the page has a button and a table with only a header row.  When the user clicks the button, I add a row to the table.  The row contains some data that I have placed into some dynamic controls.  (For the Proof-of-concept, let's assume textboxes.)  When the user changes the value in one of the text boxes on one of the rows, I want the text color to change.  What I'm trying to do right now is create a javascript function and set that up as the event handler for the text box.  Now, If this were a static text box that I defined in the .aspx, this would be a no-brainer.  But since I'm dynamically adding it to the page in the c# code-behind, how can I tell it to call this javascript function when the text changes?  (Or is this not possible?)

Note:  I had this mostly working using c#.  I added a new event handler for the .TextChanged event and set the AutoPostback to true.  The user had to leave the text box before the postback would fire and the event would change the font color.  But there were other issues that were causing problems.  So I'm hoping this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this onBlur or TextChanged and substitute whichever color you desire:

```
function ChangeColor() {
            var a = $('input[id*="TextBoxID"]');
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                a[i].setAttribute("BackColor", #efefef);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not the javascript that I was having trouble with.  How do I tell the text box (that was added dynamically, in the code behind) to call that function when the text in the text box changes?

Comment: What issues did you have using the TextChanged event? Can you post some code?

Comment: Apparently, what I needed to do is actually fairly common.  (I just didn't know what to search for to find my answer.)  In the code-behind, I needed to set the onChanged attribute with something like this:  MyTextBox.Attributes["onchange"] = "javascript: ChangeColor()";